# Publishing PermissionDenied desc = User not authorized to perform this action. Google Cloud Pub Sub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am getting error as

```
account_service_util_Error_:  failed to publish to PubSub: rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = User not authorized to perform this action.
rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = User not authorized to perform this action.true
```

I have added Owner,editor,Pub sub owner,publisher ,subscriber and owner rights.
Please help me with this.

[image]

Comment: You have added these permissions to which service account? Show your code where you are using this service account.

Comment: Yes, it would be good to see the code or mechanism you are using to use the service account in question when publishing.